# Classes not clearing when removing the ckeditor instance

Tags: model-view-controller, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I have a form where I need to add ckeditor for two textarea fields. I am calling the ckeditor as follows:

```
  <tr>
                                    <td class="tch col-sm-3 col-xs-4">
                                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.offer_details)
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="tc1 col-sm-9 col-xs-8" colspan="3">
                                        @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.offer_details, new { @class = "form-control offer_details", @id = "offer_details" })
                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.offer_details, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="tch col-sm-3 col-xs-4">
                                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.offer_contact_info)
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="tc1 col-sm-9 col-xs-8" colspan="3">
                                        @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.offer_contact_info, new { @class = "form-control offer_contact_info", @id = "offer_contact_info", @rows = 5 })
                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.offer_contact_info, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
```

and the script is as follows

```
 <script>
                            $('.offer_details').click(function () {
                                DestroyAllCKEDITOR("offer_details");
                                editor = CKEDITOR.replace('offer_details', {
                                    filebrowserUploadUrl: "../../ckeditor/Upload.ashx"
                                });  
                            });
                            $('.offer_contact_info').click(function () {
                                DestroyAllCKEDITOR("offer_contact_info");
                                editor = CKEDITOR.replace('offer_contact_info', {
                                    filebrowserUploadUrl: "../../ckeditor/Upload.ashx"
                                });
                            });
                            function DestroyAllCKEDITOR(editorname) {
                                //Destroy all existing instances
                                for (name in CKEDITOR.instances) {
                                    if (name != editorname) {
                                        var editor = CKEDITOR.instances[name];
                                        if ((typeof (editor) != 'undefined') && (editor != null)) {
                                            editor.destroy(true);
                                            editor = undefined;
                                        }
                                    }
                                };
                            }
                        </script>
```

I am destroying the ckeditor instances, but a tab under image called 'Response Visibilty' is displayed the number of times I click the text area. How can i solve this. [image]

Comment: having the same issue, no answer?